# Hose came off washing machine

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine

The hot water hose came free from the washer last night. Do I need to replace the inlet valve? Is this a simple thing to do?

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just screw the hose back on? The wear on the last thread of the adaptor suggests it wasn't properly installed; did the hose coming off break anything?

Comment: No, I think the thread was faulty when I bought the washer last year. I was unable to get the hose to screw on correctly. I installed a new inlet valve ($160 later), and the hoses attached no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn's out I needed to replace the ENTIRE inlet valve. Was very easy to do, all you need is a screwdriver, a YouTube video (just Google your washer + replace inlet valve), and a wrench to slightly tighten the hoses. Not a cheap fix ($160 CDN), but everything works now.

Comment: I think you could have probably just put some plumbers tape at the end of the adaptor and screwed the hose back on....

Comment: That was my first attempt at a dirty fix, it very much did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The threads appear to be slightly damaged due to cross-threading or impact during transport or installation. This doesn't warrant a valve replacement, however.

Use a triangular file or other tool to trace the threads and remove any material that prohibits proper alignment of the hose threads. As a last resort, simply cut off the first few threads with a hack saw or rotary tool.

The rubber washer in the end of the hose makes the seal, so the condition of the threads isn't critical as long as it allows you to tighten the hose. There's no doubt in my mind that the threads shown in the photo are up to the task.